# HTML Form Will Not Submit Correctly

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit

This form will not submit for some weird reason. Can anyone spot the issue?

```
<form id="sendEmailForm-1" method="post" action="">
  <input type="text" name="client-name" class="form-control" autofocus="" placeholder="What is your name?" required="">

  <div class="space-15"></div>
  <input type="text" name="client-email" class="form-control" autofocus="" placeholder="What is your email?" required="">

  <div class="space-15"></div>
  <input type="text" name="email-subject" class="form-control" autofocus="" placeholder="Give it a good subject" required="">

  <div class="space-15"></div>
  <textarea type="text" name="email-body" class="form-control textarea-lg" autofocus="" placeholder="What is your question?" required=""></textarea>

  <div class="space-15"></div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-dark btn-block" id="send-ask-message">Send!</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Please post all of the relevant code.

Comment: Does this give a 405 error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Check your Action is empty at the first line of code

```
<form id="sendEmailForm-1" method="post" action="">
```

you need to specify where you want to submit your form

if it don't resolves issue then please post more code relevant to this form

thanks

Comment: An empty action will post to the same page, which may (or may not) be what the OP wants to do.

Comment: what if he have external page?
that's why asked for more code so that find where it is giving error

Comment: It may indeed solve his problem, but by writing "you need to specify," you imply that `action` requires a value.